# Raster Vector stack

Tags: python, image, numpy

I want a clipped image of NDVI for a particular area. I did raster calculation for getting the image with NDVI values. After that I tried extraction function clipper.

In this function we have to use two inputs one is raster input which in this case processed NDVI image, and another is mask layer. So for mask layer I used a shapefile to clip the raster image.

This is fine working fine, but when I'm importing that clipped NDVI image in Python shell it is giving large range of data sets when it's range lies in between -1 to -1. So what shall I do for this particular one..?

```
In [1] from PIL import Image 
In [2] from PIL import * 
In [3] import numpy as np
In [4] ndvi = Image.open('/home/gajanan/ndvi.tif) 
In [5] ndviarray = np.array(ndvi) 
In [6] ndviarray 
Out[6]: array([[ -3.40282347e+38, -3.40282347e+38, -3.40282347e+38, ..., -3.40282347e+38, -3.40282347e+38, -3.40282347e+38], [ -3.40282347e+38, -3.40282347e+38, -3.40282347e+38, ..., -3.40282347e+38, -3.40282347e+38, -3.40282347e+38], ..., ]], dtype=float32) 
In [7] ndviarray.mean() 
Out[7] -inf –
```

Comment: Hi Gajanan, could you supply some example of code? It would make it easier to have a good idea of what is happening.

Comment: You have to filter NO DATA values

Comment: In [1] from PIL import Image
In [2] from PIL import *
In [3] import numpy as np
In [4] ndvi = Image.open('/home/gajanan/ndvi.tif)
In [5] ndviarray = np.array(ndvi)
In [6] ndviarray
Out[6]: 
array([[ -3.40282347e+38,  -3.40282347e+38,  -3.40282347e+38, ...,
         -3.40282347e+38,  -3.40282347e+38,  -3.40282347e+38],
       [ -3.40282347e+38,  -3.40282347e+38,  -3.40282347e+38, ...,
         -3.40282347e+38,  -3.40282347e+38,  -3.40282347e+38],
       ..., ]], dtype=float32)
In [7] ndviarray.mean()
Out[7] -inf

Comment: I filtered no data values in properties.. It's giving data matrix as like in previous comment.